# Getting element from list. Dojo

Tags: javascript, web, dojo

I using dojo.

```
  dojo.ready(function ()
    var input = dojo.query(".dojo_input"); //i have about 5 elements with ".dojo_input" class
    input.on("click", function(i) {
       console.log(input[i]);
       // function 
       });
    });
```

So question is: I get undefined element, so i can't use any function on it. How i can get uniqe element from list. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

EDIT1:
Have a look at the jsfiddle over here http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/YYyH9.

you can use the foreach function on the query result as shown below

```
dojo.ready(function (){
    var input = dojo.query(".dojo_input"); //i have about 5 elements with ".dojo_input" class
    input.forEach(function(node, index, arr){ // node is the elment
        console.log("Index"+index);
        dojo.on(node,"click", function() {
            console.log("Clicked!");
            // function 
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: The argument to the `on` callback is an event, not an index. Even if you remove that argument, this will not work; `index` will always be 4 at the time the callback is triggered.

Comment: Oops! classic closure mistake... Need to an IIFE to bind the index.

Comment: I try to use it, and result is (on page ready): 
http://screencast.com/t/xVAL0PY3

Comment: I have created an example over here http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/YYyH9/. Have a look at it. It works as expected. Click the **Run** menu to run the example and click on the DIV elements.

Comment: I can't use this version, because i must use in `onclick` event `.next()` on node. So, i can't use event. 

If you are intrested, i want do some hint areas, that show when you click on input. http://jsfiddle.net/uniqalien/95khM/

Answer (score 1):

The parameter passed to `on`'s callback is an Event object, not an index. Try doing

```
input.on("click", function(e) { //event object is conventionally named "e" or "evt"
    console.log(e);
});
```

IIRC, the input node itself should be available in the `e.target` property.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html#id4

Comment: When i try to use it console.log(e) returns me:
MouseEvent {dataTransfer: null, toElement: input#fio_dojo.dijitReset.dijitInputInner,...
When i try to use e.append("") it says me: 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function main.html:84
(anonymous function)

Comment: @uniqalien: as expected, e is an Event object, not a Dom node. You can get the dom  node with e.target and then do the appropriate DOM methods with it.

Answer (score -1):

I take code that proposed by frank and use `dojo.connect` instead of `dojo.on`

```
dojo.ready(function (){
    var input = dojo.query(".dojo_input"); //i have about 5 elements with ".dojo_input" class
    input.forEach(function(node, index, arr){ // node is the elment
        dojo.connect(node, "onclick", function() {
        console.log("Clicked!" + node);
        // function
            dojo.query(node).after("");
        });
    });
});
```

And to use any function on node, i use `dojo.query(node)`. 
Thanks.

Comment: have you seen the fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/YYyH9 It uses dojo.on which is the new event handling function of dojo.